# Gradle setup for OCI Java SDK in Intellij

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I'm trying to setup Gradle for OCI Java SDK using implementation 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-bom:1.8.0' provided in https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.oracle.oci.sdk/oci-java-sdk-bom/1.8.0/pom and **getting Plugin not found  error**.

How can I setup Gradle properly for OCI

Below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.oracle.oci.sdk' version '1.8.0'
}

group 'mysample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-bom:1.8.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring's Dependency Management Plugin (https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/).

Example:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-bom:1.13.2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.oracle.oci.sdk:oci-java-sdk-limits'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the OCI gradle plugin at https://github.com/aalmiray/oci-gradle-plugin